# Hash with array in value

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Want to make such a conversion, but do not get right result

```
 old = {
      1 => %w(A E I O U L N R S T),
      2 => %w(D G),
      3 => %w(B C M P),
      4 => %w(F H V W Y),
      5 => %w(K),
      8 => %w(J X),
      10 => %w(Q Z)
    }

expected = {
  'a' => 1, 'b' => 3, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 2, 'e' => 1,
  'f' => 4, 'g' => 2, 'h' => 4, 'i' => 1, 'j' => 8,
  'k' => 5, 'l' => 1, 'm' => 3, 'n' => 1, 'o' => 1,
  'p' => 3, 'q' => 10, 'r' => 1, 's' => 1, 't' => 1,
  'u' => 1, 'v' => 4, 'w' => 4, 'x' => 8, 'y' => 4,
  'z' => 10
}
```

Implementing my conversion with nested loop. I thought that while inside loop is looping the outer loop will not increment. Here is my code:

```
class Etl

    def self.transform(old)

        result = {}

        old.each do |key, value|
            value.each_with_index do |v, i|
                result[v[i]] = key
            end
        end

        result

    end


end
```

Comment: The inverse hash part is interesting, but as a whole this is a bad question because downcasing has nothing to do with it. You should separate them into individual questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use index, just use `v`:

```
def self.transform(old)
    result = {}
    old.each do |key, value|
        value.each do |v|
            result[v.downcase] = key
        end
    end
    result
end
```

NOTE: used [`String#downcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-downcase) to match the expected hash's key case.

---

Alternative using [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```
def self.transform(old)
    old.flat_map { |key, value|
      value.map { |v|
        [v.downcase, key]
      }
    }.sort.to_h
end
```

Comment: You can incorporate `sort` before `to_h`.

Comment: @Stefan, Thank you for the comment. I added `.sort` before `.to_h` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
old.flat_map { |k, v| v.map(&:downcase).product([k]) }.sort.to_h
  #=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>3, "c"=>3, "d"=>2, "e"=>1, "f"=>4, "g"=>2, "h"=>4, "i"=>1,
  #    "j"=>8, "k"=>5, "l"=>1, "m"=>3, "n"=>1, "o"=>1, "p"=>3, "q"=>10, "r"=>1,
  #    "s"=>1, "t"=>1, "u"=>1, "v"=>4, "w"=>4, "x"=>8, "y"=>4, "z"=>10}
```